# Deploying using ansible resets symfony cache file permissions on production environment

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, nginx, ansible

I'm using Symfony 5.0.7

My live deploy ansible `after-symlink-shared.yaml` file:

```
---

- name: Set up infrastructure-related parameters
  template:
    src: '{{ playbook_dir }}/templates/.env_live.dist'
    dest: '{{ ansistrano_release_path.stdout }}/.env'


- name: Install Composer dependencies
  composer:
    command: install
    arguments: --classmap-authoritative
    no_dev: no
    optimize_autoloader: yes
    working_dir: '{{ ansistrano_release_path.stdout }}'

- name: Clear the cache
  command: 'php {{ release_console_path }} cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod'

- name: Warm up the cache
  command: 'php {{ release_console_path }} cache:warmup --env=prod'

- name: Create DB if not exists
  command: 'php {{ release_console_path }} doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists --env=prod'
  register: create_db_output
  changed_when: create_db_output.stdout is not search('already exists. Skipped')

- name: Run migrations
  command: 'php {{ release_console_path }} doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction --env=prod'
  register: run_migrations_output
  changed_when: run_migrations_output.stdout is not search('No migrations to execute')


- name: Install bundle assets
  command: 'php {{ release_console_path }} assets:install --symlink --env=prod {{ ansistrano_release_path.stdout }}/public'


- name: Copy build directory
  command: 'cp -a {{ ansistrano_release_path.stdout }}/public/build /var/www/project/public'
  tags:
    - deploy
```

The deployment works perfectly, however every time I deploy to the server, my production environment hits a 500 error.

I take a look at my `prod.log` file to understand what is causing the error and I get the following:

```
[2020-05-09 21:40:59] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/var/cache/prod/profiler)." at /var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php line 43 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/var/cache/prod/profiler). at /var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php:43)"} []

[2020-05-09 21:40:59] php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Exception: Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/var/cache/prod/profiler). {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/var/cache/prod/profiler). at /var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php:43)"} []

[2020-05-09 21:40:59] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/var/cache/prod/profiler)." at /var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php line 43 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/var/cache/prod/profiler). at /var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php:43)"} []

[2020-05-09 21:40:59] php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Exception: Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/var/cache/prod/profiler). {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/var/cache/prod/profiler). at /var/www/project/symfony/releases/20200509213543Z/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php:43)"}
```

This looks like a permissions issue because every time I deploy, this error comes up. Is is possible I can do something from the NGINX perspective to ensure this functions properly? Or is this an ansible solution? I'm trying to avoid manually fixing these errors with each deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

It was purely a permissions issue that I had to firstly go to the highest level folder of where the var prod folder was and updated the permissions using `chown` then updated the permissions for all folder below recursively using `chmod` to ensure everything else moving forward would be written just as the parent was.

Answer (score 0):

The user running the deployment seems to be different than the one that runs php, that's why the user doesn't have permissions to the `cache` directory after `cache:warmup` is run.

You have several options:

- Change the user the app runs under:
  Since you say you are using nginx I guess you are running php-fpm. You can change the `user` and `group` parameters in your `php-fpm.conf` to the one running the deployment. If you are running multiple applications, create a new pool. (Here's slightly outdated [guide](https://gist.github.com/fyrebase/62262b1ff33a6aaf5a54#separate-pools) to fpm and pools to get you going, and the [FPM reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php)).
- Adjust primary groups and [`umask`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html) or [`acl`s](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists) so both users have access.
- Run the `cache` tasks as the `php` user using [`become`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-directives).
- Fix permissions as part of the deploy process by running an ansible task. You can use the [file module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html) for this. You can either use open permissions or use `become`.

Keep in mind that using `become` (the last two options) requires changing the [`sudoers` file](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/configuring-linux-sudoers-file/) so the `deploy` user can act as the `php` user.

If you have an `uploads` directory under `public` that needs write access by the php process, you need to fix those permissions too.

Comment: Can you show me how to add a new pool? There's nothing to change in my file.

Comment: @Majo0od In fairness, pools are only needed if you have multiple apps that require isolation, if it's a dedicated server changing the main pool as indicated should be enough.

Comment: A couple of things:

How do I fix the permissions using umask or acl so that php has the user access?

Also the code you provided, is that for an ansible task or adjusting the sudoers?

Where do I go to adjust the sudoers?

Comment: @Majo0od The `umask` is set in the user profile or `.bashrc`. The [sudoers](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/configuring-linux-sudoers-file/) file is `/etc/sudoers/`. The code provided is an ansible task.

Comment: Yeah this didn't help. The ansible code didn't work. I'm not entirely sure how to use umaks in conjunction with php. When I added php in the sudoers it didn't do anything

Comment: Can you write out the ansible task so I can try it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue happens probably because ansible runs on `root` user, but PHP server didn't

Try to add the last step for change ownership of directory in the playbook

```
- name: Fix user rights
  command: 'chown -R www-data: /var/www/project/public'
  tags:
    - deploy
```

in my example ownership grants to user `www-data` (default), but in your case it can be different.

For check right user, use command

```
cd /var/www/project && ls -la
```